# I'm writing a program that generates Random Race/class for eq for a twitch streaming app

Tags: java, string, if-statement, random

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ClassNameGenerator {

    private static JLabel label;
    private static JLabel label2;

    public static void main (String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("EQStreamTool");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,350);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel (new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 5));
        for (int i =0; i <10; i++) {
        }
        frame.add(panel);
        JButton button = new JButton("Generate Class/Race");
        panel.add(button);
        label = new JLabel();
        panel.add(label);
        button.addActionListener(new Action());
        label2 = new JLabel();
        panel.add(label2);
        button.addActionListener(new Action());
    }

    static class Action implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            String[] races = {"Barbarian", "Dark Elf", "Dwarf", "Erudite", "Gnome", "Ogre", "Troll", "Wood Elf", "Half Elf", "Halfling", "High Elf", "Human", "Iksar"};
            String[] classes = {"Bard", "Druid", "Cleric", "Enchanter", "Magician", "Monk", "Necromancer", "Paladin", "Ranger", "Rogue", "Shadowknight", "Warrior", "wizard"};
            String[] barbClasses = {"Rogue", "Shaman", "Warrior"};
            String[] delfClasses = {"Cleric", "Enchanter", "Magician", "Necromancer", "Rogue", "Shadowknight", "Warrior", "Wizard"};
            String[] dwarfClasses = {"Rogue", "Paladin", "Warrior"};
            String[] eruditeClasses = {"Cleric", "Enchanter", "Magician", "Necromancer", "Paladin", "Shadowknight", "Wizard"};
            String[] gnomeClasses = {"Cleric", "Enchanter", "Magician", "Necromancer", "Paladin", "Rogue", "Shadowknight", "Warrior", "Wizard"};
            String[] halfelfClasses = {"Bard", "Druid", "Paladin", "Ranger", "Rogue", "Shadowknight", "Warrior", "Wizard"};
            String[] halflingClasses = {"Rogue", "Cleric", "Warrior", "Druid", "Paladin", "Ranger"};
            String[] highelfClasses = {"Cleric", "Enchanter", "Magician", "Paladin", "Wizard"};
            String[] humanClasses = {"Rogue", "Bard", "Warrior", "Cleric", "Druid", "Enchanter", "Magician", "Monk", "Necromancer", "Paladin", "Ranger", "Shadowknight", "Wizard"};
            String[] iksarClasses = {"Monk", "Shaman", "Warrior", "Necromancer", "Shadowknight"};
            String[] ogreClasses = {"Shadowknight", "Shaman", "Warrior"};
            String[] trollClasses = {"Shadwknight", "Shaman", "Warrior"};
            String[] woodelfClasses = {"Bard", "Druid", "Ranger", "Rogue", "Warrior"};

            int random = (int) (Math.random()*races.length);
            int random2 = (int) (Math.random()*classes.length);

            label.setText("Your Race is: "  + races[random]); 
            label2.setText("Your Class is: " + classes[random2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Ok so what I am trying to do is get a program that can create a random class/race combo from the old game everquest.  I want to make sure the program takes into consideration the class race restrictions.  so I made a bunch of Strings and I can't seem to be able to get a random class based on a random race.

So it should work like this 
program picks a race, and it randomly selects a class that only that race can play.  Hence all the strings.  Please any help would be appreciated so i can move on to phase two of this project.

Also a side note how do I make it so the button stays on top and the text it pops out displays under it?

Comment: also right now it pops out a random race and class, but it doesnt take into account that you can not be some classes as a certain race.  thats why i made the other strings.

Comment: you can use a 2d array

Comment: i should also say i dont know a lot about java. It took me 10 hours to get this done, and i sourced it from several different sites.   Java coding is kinda hard lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion for you to your first problem is to use Enum . I have created sample enum class which would be something like ,

```
public enum RestrictedComboEnum {

Barbarian(new String[] { "bard", "druid" }), 
Dwarf(new String[] { "hello","trial" });

RestrictedComboEnum(String[] classes) {
    this.classes = classes;
}

String[] classes;

public String[] getClasses() {
    return this.classes;
}
```

}

Now, remove your String array of race and classes from your above code. Instead, select one of the `enum` as your races (instead of the string you been doing) by calling `getEnumConstants()` on that `enum` class which returns array of all `enum` , in your case is all `Races` with valid classes. Now call the get method in this `enum` and it returns whatever possible classes you entered for that race `enum`. You can randomly select the class as it is array of string and move forward from there.

The relevant code on your above mentioned class would be like this :

```
        RestrictedComboEnum[] combinations = RestrictedComboEnum.class
                .getEnumConstants();

        int random = (int) (Math.random() * combinations.length);

        RestrictedComboEnum selectedCombo = combinations[random];

        int random2 = (int) (Math.random() * selectedCombo.getClasses().length);

        label.setText("Your Race is: " + combinations[random]);
        label2.setText("Your Class is: "+ selectedCombo.getClasses()[random2]);
```

in above example, when application selects `Barbarian` as race, the possible selection would be either `bard` or `druid`, and for `Dwarf` it would be `hello` and `trial`. So fill the `enum` as per your need.

From your comments, you seem to be very new in Java, So just for learning purpose too, you can try using Enum , because you gonna need them.
This should make your life lot easier then using 2d array when your code grows.

Comment: your right im new, very new.  But im going to look into more enums and 2d arrays just to get familiar with both.

Comment: that fixed it right up.  Thank you so much.  Now if i could just format the way the jfram pops things into the box.

Comment: You need to provide the position for the labels when you add the labels on panel. look it up , it wont't be hard. Personally, i prefer grid bag layout , so that I can add anything where I want.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly ,you can use a 2d  array .for example

```
String[][] raceAndClasses={{"Barbarian","Dark Elf","Dwarf"},{"Bard", "Druid", "Cleric"},{"Rogue", "Shaman", "Warrior"}};
```

inside a  array you can specified all races it has .so when you pick a class randomly you can pick a relevant random race

Comment: this will probably help, looking it up now to see how i would set it up thanks

Comment: i will give more detailed example @JeremyZavala